# Web performance isn't up to snuff... what's the new "Microsoft Way"?

Tags: wpf, windows, silverlight, platform

Looking for opinions.  I'm working on a mid-sized 3-tier ASP.NET project (.NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005) with an Oracle on Unix back-end, some beefy MS web servers, and IE browser clients.  Performance is pretty bad, and users feel the UI looks outdated as well.  We may have an opportunity soon to redesign and rewrite the entire application from the ground up, and I'm wondering what the current or recommended MS platform is.

I was involved with WPF and Silverlight on a different contract when MS downgraded support for Silverlight in favor of "HTML5" for Windows 8 and Windows Phone a few years back.  I'm not trying to start a flame war between how long Silverlight or even WPF will be around, but I'm looking for some modern alternatives as of today, April 2013.  The one requirement we can't get around is that we can't install something on each and every user PC throughout the client organization.

My own background is in WinForms and C# more so than any of the above, but everywhere I turn it seems developing any new LOB apps in WinForms isn't done much anymore.

Whatever happened to the Application Server platform and apps run thru Remote Desktop?  Does it still make sense to develop desktop apps and deploy to app servers and just put a shortcut on each user's desktop, or even map a drive letter like we used to do back in the day?

Your $0.02 would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't install because it would be too hard/time consuming or because of other reasons? If it is the former, then there are many solutions for remote deployment. Especially if computers are in domain.

Comment: In addition to Euphoric's comment, I would like to mention the Click-once deployment feature in Visual Studio. This can be useful if you don't have a complicated deployment requirement. You can set it up so that each time the user starts the application, it will auto check for updates. Each time you make an update to the code, you just need to publish to one location.

Comment: Can't install because it would be too time consuming and our user base is geographically separated.

I'll check into click-once auto deployment.  We do have several beefy web servers that could be repurposed to serve as app servers.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely consider doing it as an internal web site.

The UI would be HTML5 using the  "single page application" (SPA) for each function you need. Each function would be on a page that is loaded when the user needs it. The javascript/ajax code in the browser would interact with the web server which feeds back the raw data needed to be displayed.

Using Active Directory, you can have full security and customization per person.

If you need lots of interactivity, then you'd also want to consider including SignalR in the mix. (That is one of the "new" MS tools!)

Comment: I would add that you may need to use shiv's (or the like) to degrade gracefully in older browsers in case the client does not have HTML 5 supported browsers

Comment: As per other comments, as of April 2013, you'd want to be using ASP.NET MVC4 Razor with C# on .NET 4.5 using Visual Studio 2012.  On the client, JQuery and other libraries, such as Twitter BootStrap and KnockoutJS, are invaluable.

Comment: I think that's the list of tools and tech I was looking for.

Comment: Glad that helps... for database, Entity Framework is good. But in your environment, choose carefully whether "code first" is good for you. If you have pre-existing databases, or databases that other systems would be using, then you likely will want to avoid "code first".

Answer (score 1):

If you can't install anything in the end users' PCs then go ASP.Net. Anything else will require installation.

You can make a web application more appealing to the users by having a good designer and a LOT of javascript. Not remotely comparable to the power and beauty of WPF, but that's your best bet.

WPF is part of the .Net framework and will not run without it installed.

Silverlight could also be an option, but it still requires an installation (although minimal, 4 MB, less-than-2 minute install), but an install anyways.

WinRT only works in Windows 8. It's not supported in lower versions (Vista, XP, 7). So I don't think it's an option as of now (unless all your users have Windows 8, of course).

And no, winforms is not an option. It's also part of the .Net framework, and even if you could get it installed, it doesn't make any sense having to deal with the limitations of it, having many much much better technologies at your disposal.

Comment: I'd like to recommend ASP.NET MVC over WebForms, seriously.

Comment: @DavidTansey Right. Im primarily a desktop developer, so I don't have much experience  with either.

Comment: @DavidTansey And I would recommend any modern desktop technology over anything web related. (and I don't consider WebForms modern).

Comment: @Euphoric Agreed, but the OP stated he cannot install anything in the users' machines.

Comment: I'm the OP.  Sorry, I meant to say our userbase doesn't want to have to install something new upon every release.  One-time installs of Silverlight or .NET libs would be allowed... they just don't want to have to perform manual updates when we release subsequent versions.  Pushed update might be allowed; I'll check into that.  I'd hope an auto-update feature that runs each time the application is started would be good too, but I'll have to check on that as well.

Comment: @JeffElliott Then go WPF application + ClickOnce deployment. ClickOnce auto-updates when needed at startup. It's great. WPF is also great. You can achieve really good things with much less effort.